# WordPress body margin-top issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So, I'm making a custom WordPress theme, which you can see at http://staging.gencormortgage.com/sandbox/wordpress/. It displays properly in all browsers but Google Chrome (and possibly Safari, can't test that one) - I want the lines at the top to be all the way at the top of the screen. I've tried `body{ margin-top:0 auto; }`, but this only works on Opera and Firefox, but has a 28px blank space at the top in Google Chrome. If I change the `margin-top` to `-28px`, it doesn't display properly in Opera and Firefox. How can I overcome this browser compatibility issue?

Comment: I should also not that I'm using `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the head of the theme, before my custom stylesheet.

Comment: what do you mean "all the way at the top of the screen"? I'm using chrome, and I see a green and gray line at the top, so I'm assuming that's how it's suppose to be.

Comment: `- I want the lines at the top to be all the way at the top of the screen.` Can you clarify what you meant by that?

Comment: http://d.pr/i/NFOV <- I have this 28px blank space at the top of the body I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the admin bar.

You can disable it by putting the following in funcitons.php

```
wp_deregister_script('admin-bar');
wp_deregister_style('admin-bar');
remove_action('wp_footer','wp_admin_bar_render',1000);
```

By the way it's only displayed when you are logged in.

Alternatively there is a [lite plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/global-admin-bar-hide-or-remove/) you can download to hide it.

Comment: Thank you, I will mark this as the answer, because it is the best answer to my situation out of the offered ones. Adding `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false'); ` to my functions.php solved my problem. Thanks!